# vncviewer connection refused (61)

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop, centos, vnc

I have a root access to VPS (centos 6). I have installed VNCServer using this guide line
http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/how-to-setup-vnc-server-on-centos-5-x-fedora-11/

Everything goes perfectly and server is running via termina. Now I am trying to connect to that server via vncviewer (mac os). but its giving me error

```
Connection refused (61)
```

I am providing only the IP address of the VPS, maybe I also needed port address? How to configure port on vncserver? or its something else?

Answer (score 7):

I've just had this problem. I resolved it by explicitly stating the port number when connectin from the client. E.g.:

```
1.23.45.67:5901
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

First, temporary disable iptables using this command:

```
service iptables stop
```

Now try to connect; if the connection was successful, then try to allow VNC default port in iptables.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I installed the VNC server, then added the following to the firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
```

Then in my VNC client I connected by including the port number in the IP.

`192.168.1.253:5901`

There's no need to stop IPTABLES.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the documentation has the following:

```
$ vncdo --help
Usage: vncdo [options] CMD CMDARGS|-|filename

Command line control of a VNC server

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PASSWORD, --password=PASSWORD
                        use password to access server
  -s SERVER, --server=SERVER
                        connect to VNC server at ADDRESS[:DISPLAY|::PORT]
                        [127.0.0.1]
```

Notice the double colon, **::PORT**
So in my case, I was able to connect using:

```
vncdo -vs vncServerIP::5901  type "hello world"
```

(instead of `vncdo -vs vncServerIP:5901`)

(Also, the `-v`, verbose mode, was quite useful to see what was going on along with disabling any kind of security on the vnc server side)